# JQuery Datepicker in Zend Framework not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I made a form, which extends from `Zend_Form`, where I added a `ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_Datepicker` as you can see in this picture:

[image]

But when I view that page in the browser, the datepicker seems to work, but the layout is messed up. See this picture:

[image]

You can see that the datepicker is too small and the prev/next buttons are not shown correctly. I've tried fixing this with css:

```
.ui-datepicker-div { width: 200px; } 
.ui-datepicker-calendar { width: 200px; }
```

This helps a little, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

But as you can see, there's still a problem with the prev/next buttons. How I can I fix this?

**Update**: I fixed my problem by including another css file. Because I was using the Google CDN for jQuery and jQuery UI, I had to use the CDN also for including the css. So, by adding the following line, I solved my problem:

```
$this->jQuery()->addStyleSheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some external CSS interfering, something affecting all table cells most likely, possibly `<div>` and `<a>` elements as well.  Without a link to the actual page I can't say...but it's definitely a CSS issue, where your styles are overriding the padding/margins jQuery UI sets.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your response. I'm working with the 960 grid system and I think that caused the wrong width of the datepicker, because that part of the problem was solved when I changed the order of my css file includes (the jquery css last). However that didn't seem to solve the prev/next-button problem, so I left out any other css but still no luck. The buttons won't get on their right spot. This page is not online, so I can't show you live, but thanks again for your response. Greetz

Comment: @Brecht - ah there you go...I haven't used 960 with jQuery UI but I can easily see how that styling wouldn't get along :)